# Open results in Explorer

Tags: search, search-results, open-with-explorer

We are using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Search and we want to add a link for each result on the results page that allows the user to open the folder containing the file in Explorer. Is it possible to achieve this by using the XSL Editor for the results page?

Answer (score 1):

You could render a hyperlink and use the `NavigateHttpFolderIfSupported` method from the built in *OWS.js*:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:NavigateHttpFolderIfSupported('FolderUrlToOpen', '_blank'); return false;">open</a>
```

Replace the `FolderUrlToOpen` with the corresponding URL of the results.